# Can I use "Target: One Ally" powers on myself?

Tags: dnd-4e, artificer

I am building an Artificer, and I'm looking at some of his powers that give bonuses to allies. For example,

> **Dancing Shield.** 
>   Minor action, ranged 5, Target: One Ally.
>
> You conjure a shield of metal and magic to protect the target. The target
>   gains a +4 power bonus to AC and Reflex until the end of the
>   encounter. As a minor action, you can move the shield to a new target
>   within range.

Now I can only hope that I will be able to use powers like this on myself if need be.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Nope.** An ally is "a companion of the power's user." [Rules Compendium, 106] Powers that can affect the caster too usually bear a "You or an ally" target line.

Comment: +1. And just to intensify the answer, powers that can affect the _caster_ too usually bear a "You or an ally" target line.

Comment: @ErikBurigo Thanks. I'll edit my answer to include that.

Comment: 4e is written that there should be no rules assumptions. Powers do exactly and only what they say.

Answer (score 8):

Also, I am pretty sure there are powers with a "**Target: You or one ally**" entry. Your assumption would make them redundant, now wouldn't it?